# ¿Qué puedo hacer para validar error en un formulario antes que me accione la propiedad onsubmit en Laravel 5.2?

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

> Necesito un tipo de filtro de errores, si en caso haya errores en el
>   formulario generados por un Form Request, no me ejecute la propiedad
>   "onsubmit" del formulario que me acciona una función en javascript para imprimir.

```
{!!Form::open(array('name' => 'pasajeroForm','url'=>'generar/pasaje','method'=>'POST', 'autocomplete'=>'off' @if(empty($errors)), 'onsubmit' => 'imprimir()'@endif))!!}
    {{Form::token()}}

<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" hidden>
     <div class="form-group">
          <label for="pasCodigo">Código</label>
          <input id="pasCodigo" type="text" name="pasCodigo" class="form-control" value="{{$pasajero->PasCodigo}}">
     </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
     <button class="btn btn-md btn-block btn-primary" type="submit">Registrar Pasaje</button>
</div>

{!!Form::close()!!}
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes crear un **Request** y colocar todas las reglas que necesites validar de tu formulario.

[Form Request Validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#form-request-validation)

En el controller puedes colocar tu request

```
public function TuFuncion(TuRequestCreado $request)
```

Si pasa la validación entonces continua con lo que haga la función de tu Controller, en caso que falle hace un back() al formulario, devolviendo los errores.

Comment: Hola @Alex, si estoy usando un form request y me devuelve los errores; pero la propiedad onsubmit igual se ejecuta y me envía en este caso al preview para imprimir.

Comment: Si en tu view tienes un formulario al darle submit ejecutará el POST, pero en tu Route lo asocias a una función de un controller. En esa función colocas el Request creado con las validaciones, y no continua lo que tengas en la función del controller, por ende no debe ir a ninguna sección de imprimir.

Answer (score -1):

Con la lógica del `@if` tendrías que cargar el formulario con "un error" así la primera vez (que se muestra el form) no te pone el `onsubmit`, en la segunda vuelta (al apretar el botón submit) si no hay errores de validación le pone el `onsubmit` del print.

La primera vez que carga el formulario no hay errores, así que pone el "onsubmit"

```
 @if(empty($errors)), 'onsubmit' => 'imprimir()'@endif))!!}
```

Una opción es definir un `input` tipo `hidden` que toma valor recién al primer post, y así chequeamos que tenga un valor antiguo.

```
{!!Form::open(array(
    'name' => 'pasajeroForm',
    'url'=>'generar/pasaje',
    'method'=>'POST', 
    'autocomplete'=>'off' 

@if(empty($errors)&&old('firstrun')), 'onsubmit' => 'imprimir()'@endif))!!}

    {{Form::token()}}
<input type="hidden" name="firstrun" value="yaestuveaqui" />
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" hidden>
     <div class="form-group">
          <label for="pasCodigo">Código</label>
          <input id="pasCodigo" type="text" name="pasCodigo" class="form-control" value="{{$pasajero->PasCodigo}}">
     </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
     <button class="btn btn-md btn-block btn-primary" type="submit">Registrar Pasaje</button>
</div>

{!!Form::close()!!}
```